# How would I get the last character of a string in XSLT in order to add it to my HTML output?

Tags: xslt, substring

I am very new to XSLT and need to grab only the last letter of an XML value and add that character to my HTML output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the XPath expression

```
substring(., string-length(.), 1)
```

or, in an XSLT way

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length(.), 1)" />
```

This works, because XPath starts counting at 1 and not 0.

Comment: I checked and it seems that "1" in your XPath expression is redundant. Without the third argument this expression gets the last character anyway. Does it depend on implementation where XPath is used?

Comment: You're right. It can be omitted. I just leave it there for readability, because this way it's straightaway clear that exactly one char is returned.

Comment: And no, it shouldn't depend on the implementation.